# Why is my image not showing on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to show an image on a canvas at the top corner and the draw function is not working properly. What have I done wrong.

[image]

The above image is what I want to show on the screen.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<p><canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid black;" width="450" height="310"></canvas>
</body>


<script>
    var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");


    draw();

    function draw(){  
        var img = new Image(); 
        img.src = "t.gif";  
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);  
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You want to show "OPEN4HOURS" but you're adding "Royal Flush", "Striaght Flush"?!

Comment: @chipChocolate.py It works because the browser has the image in the cache. But if you open the fiddle in a private window, it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you attempt to draw the image immediately, before the browser has finished downloading it.

Try this instead:

```
function draw(){  
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    };
    img.src = "t.gif";  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should draw image after it is loaded

```
img.onload = function() {
    // here...
};
```